# bootstrap carousel does work, the issue is the horizontal bar that appears at the bottom

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I've tried adding a carousel, and it does appear. The only issue that comes up is with the browser's horizontal bar appearing at the bottom. And also the carousel section is not fixed.

Please check the code here: https://github.com/cseprs/page_layout_bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the below bootstrap carousel code?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <title>Project on bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--beginning of carousel-->
    <div class="container text-center my-3">
        <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <span lang="en" class="multilang">
                                            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
                                        </span>
                                        <span lang="hi" class="multilang">
                                            <h4 class="card-title">कार्ड 1</h4>
                                        </span>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some make up the bulk of the card's content.Some make up
                                            the bulk of the card's
                                            content.Some make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="carousel-inner-structure">
                                    <div class="carousel-item-rotate">
                                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                                            when an unknown printer
                                            took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                                        <a href="https://wwww.github.com" class="default-btn-style-two btn-lg"><i
                                                class="flaticon-user"></i>LOGIN</a>
                                        <a href="https://wwww.google.com" class="default-btn-style-two btn-lg"><i
                                                class="flaticon-user"></i>SIGN
                                            UP</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="carousel-inner-structure">
                                    <div class="carousel-item-rotate">
                                        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080/?wallpaper,landscape" class="img-fluid">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#myCarousel"
                    data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#myCarousel"
                    data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of carousel-->
</body>
</html>
```